# NetworkManager keeps connecting and disconnecting. How can I fix this?

Tags: networkmanager

I am using latest available builds with up to date system as follows:
Arch kernel 5.6.4-arch1-1, Openbox 3.6.1,  NetworkManager 1.24.0-1, wpa_supplicant v2.9.

I use my laptop in three geographic locations.
In each of these locations there is a unique wifi network, with it's own unique SSID that I connect to.
The laptop uses only `WPA and WPA2 Personal` protocol to connect in all three of these locations.

In two of these three locations my laptop WiFi always connects quickly, seamlessly and perfectly, without any problems.

In the third location, and only in the third location, my laptop continually cycles through WiFi disconnect & reconnect every 10 secs as outlined in the below steps

1. 5 secs, searching for network
2. 1 sec, connected to network
3. 4 secs, disconnected
4. go to 1 and start over again ...

I am able to get a network connection to the internet in this third location, as outlined in the list above, but only for about one in every 10 seconds.

This makes working in this third location impossible.

In this third location the router provides perfect wifi to every other device.
So the router does not appear to be the problem.

I have tried deleting the network manager connection profile for this third location, countless times, using the `nm-applet` GUI on the `tint2 taskbar`, and then reconnecting again to the third locations SSID with the correct password etc.
But doing this changes nothing about the problem.

I have been using this command line
`sudo killall -STOP NetworkManager`
about half way through step 2, above, to sucessfully stop the cycling and remain connected, but  this has stopped working.

So now I have an Ethernet cable plugged into the laptop, and the laptop WiFi physical switch, on the side of the laptop switched off. It connects to the internet through the attached Ethernet cable, but it looses it's connection for 5 seconds in every 10 seconds. In other words it cycles the connection, on and off, as it does with the WiFi. Again, this also only happens in the third location. Once connected I am again using
`sudo killall -STOP NetworkManager`
after the connection is established to stop the cycling.

This seems to be something to do with the laptop wifi config in the third location.

**Addition: I have added one cycle of output, from the system journal,  while the system is connecting / disconnecting, below**

Command, `journalctl -ef`, produced this output.

`network is down. This is the end of last connection / disconnection cycle and the beginning of the next`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 dhcpcd[5050]: ps_bpf_recvbpf: Network is down
```

`preamble`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May 23 13:46:52 t430 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
```

`registering ipv4 address`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.106.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
```

`withdrawing ipv4 address`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.106.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: deleting route to 192.168.1.0/24
May 23 13:46:52 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: deleting default route via 192.168.1.1
May 23 13:46:52 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <warn>  [1590238012.8707] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'datastream5'
```

`registering ipv4 address again`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.106.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
May 23 13:46:52 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238012.8775] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238012.8778] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
May 23 13:46:52 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
May 23 13:46:52 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238012.8778] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
```

`registering ipv6 address`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Registering new address record for fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759 on wlp3s0.*.

May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759 on wlp3s0.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238012.8822] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> scanning
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.

`withdrawing ipv4 address`
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.106.
May 23 13:46:52 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

`new ipv4 mac address`

```
May 23 13:46:52 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: new hardware address: ca:b3:01:7c:20:73
```

`disconnected`

```
May 23 13:46:56 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238016.0852] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

`NetworkManager succeeds at something`

```
May 23 13:47:00 t430 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
May 23 13:47:00 t430 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

May 23 13:47:00 t430 kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1590238020.888:153): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.4312] policy: auto-activating connection 'datastream5' (4c200721-a84a-4619-9d08-319531f8c338)
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.4322] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'datastream5' (4c200721-a84a-4619-9d08-319531f8c338)
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.4324] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.4335] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING

May 23 13:47:02 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: new hardware address: 6c:88:14:62:84:3c
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.4486] device (wlp3s0): set-hw-addr: reset MAC address to 6C:88:14:62:84:3C (preserve)
```

`scanning for connection`

```
May 23 13:47:02 t430 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
May 23 13:47:02 t430 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0

May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8441] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8450] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'datastream5' has security, but secrets are required.
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8451] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8491] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8512] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8519] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8525] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'datastream5' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8526] Config: added 'ssid' value 'datastream5'
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8526] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8526] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8527] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8527] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8527] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8794] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
May 23 13:47:02 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238022.8920] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 70:4f:57:97:52:06 (SSID='datastream5' freq=2447 MHz)
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: authenticate with 70:4f:57:97:52:06
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to 70:4f:57:97:52:06 (try 1/3)
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: authenticated
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: associate with 70:4f:57:97:52:06 (try 1/3)
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1197] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with 70:4f:57:97:52:06 (SSID='datastream5' freq=2447 MHz)
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1226] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 70:4f:57:97:52:06 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=3)
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: Associated with 70:4f:57:97:52:06
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: associated
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1533] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4way_handshake
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 70:4f:57:97:52:06 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 70:4f:57:97:52:06 completed [id=0 id_str=]
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: carrier acquired
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1680] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
```

`#########################################################################################################`

```
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1681] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "datastream5"


May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1683] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1688] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Registering new address record for fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759 on wlp3s0.*.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: IAID 14:62:84:3c
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: adding address fe80::c685:c3d0:8b05:a9e5
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Registering new address record for fe80::c685:c3d0:8b05:a9e5 on wlp3s0.*.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1957] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '86400'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.1.1 0.0.0.0'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option expiry               => '1590324426'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option ip_address           => '192.168.1.106'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1958] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1959] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option routers              => '192.168.1.1'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1960] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.1975] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.106.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dbus-daemon[453]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=0 pid=454 comm="/usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Dynamic Linker Cache being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Journal Catalog being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Commit a transient machine-id on disk being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Update is Completed being skipped.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dbus-daemon[453]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.2125] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.2128] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.2132] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.2143] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.2145] policy: set 'datastream5' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1590238026.208:154): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dunst[1185]: WARNING: No icon found in path: 'nm-signal-75'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.2232] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.106
May 23 13:47:06 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238026.3305] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: leased 192.168.1.106 for 86400 seconds
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
May 23 13:47:06 t430 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
May 23 13:47:06 t430 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-hostnamed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1590238026.351:155): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-hostnamed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
May 23 13:47:06 t430 audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=19 op=UNLOAD
May 23 13:47:06 t430 audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=18 op=UNLOAD
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: audit: type=1334 audit(1590238026.391:156): prog-id=19 op=UNLOAD
May 23 13:47:06 t430 kernel: audit: type=1334 audit(1590238026.391:157): prog-id=18 op=UNLOAD
May 23 13:47:06 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=9999 txrate=13000
May 23 13:47:06 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: soliciting an IPv6 router
May 23 13:47:08 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: Router Advertisement from fe80::724f:57ff:fe97:5206
May 23 13:47:08 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238028.0508] dhcp6 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 23 13:47:08 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <warn>  [1590238028.0510] device (wlp3s0): failure to start DHCPv6: failed to start client: Address already in use
May 23 13:47:08 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238028.0510] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'dhcp-start-failed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')


May 23 13:47:08 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238028.0526] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
May 23 13:47:08 t430 kernel: wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 70:4f:57:97:52:06 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 23 13:47:08 t430 dunst[1185]: WARNING: No icon found in path: 'nm-no-connection'
May 23 13:47:08 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: soliciting a DHCPv6 lease
May 23 13:47:08 t430 wpa_supplicant[570]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=70:4f:57:97:52:06 reason=3 locally_generated=1
May 23 13:47:08 t430 dhcpcd[492]: wlp3s0: carrier lost



May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759.
May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Interface wlp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.106.
May 23 13:47:08 t430 NetworkManager[454]: <info>  [1590238028.0927] device (wlp3s0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to 66:51:DB:82:D6:15 (scanning)
May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c685:c3d0:8b05:a9e5 on wlp3s0.
May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::fd81:7780:6410:e759 on wlp3s0.
May 23 13:47:08 t430 avahi-daemon[451]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.106 on wlp3s0.


May 23 13:47:08 t430 dhcpcd[5441]: ps_bpf_recvbpf: Network is down
```

Comment: I would start by looking into log (e.g. syslog) files to see if anything triggers the reconnect. Maybe there are some rules in the router that prevent a clean connect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@eblock's comment on the question, above, suggested looking at the system log.

I did this and identified, at least in part, a working solution, for the problematic third location, as described above.

The network connection cycling has stopped and the connection is now stable.

This is not to say that I have got to the root of the problem, but I may have.

Here is the solution I have:

1. re-booted the laptop, and let it begin cycling the wi-fi network connection on and off.
2. In a terminal, typed, `journalctl -ef`, and watched system live journal output cycle through conenction and disconnection steps as outlined above.
3. outputed the journal to a text file with `journalctl -ef > journal_output.txt`
4. opened this in `vim` text editor and identified the part relating to one cycle through conenct and disconnect only, about 14 secs of infornmation only.

I have added this system journal output to the question above, as an amendment.

From this output I was able to identify that either the router was not issuing an ipv6 address, or that the laptop was, for whatever reason, not able to set up an ipv6 address up and that this was causing 'NetworkManager` to disconenct the network conenction.

This problem might have been caused by a recent router firmware upgrade, however I have an identical laptop with, more or less identical software installed, which does not have this network connection issue. Also other devices on the router LAN do not experience this cyclic connect / disconnect problem. That said, I think it may, I'm not certian on this, have been at about the time of the router firmware upgrade, that this problem began.

**The fix**
To fix this I simply disabled ipv6 connections, for both wifi and ethernet cable connections, in the `nm-applet` network manager gui tab for the third location only. After disabling, both wifi and cable ethernet connections connect to the network in a durable consistent way that does not cycle through connect and disconnect.

Comment: What if you need ipv6?

Comment: I also have this issues with my laptop, when connect to some specific switches at work, but only with Linux. The same laptop when boot to Windows doesn't suffer the repeatedly-disconnect-connect loop.

Comment: Thanks for both the question and the answer. I have almost exactly the same problem, and after "resolving" it by disabling IPv6, I can finally get a stable connection. Did you finally figure out the root cause of what was going wrong when IPv6 was enabled?

Answer (score 4):

### Debug

Another way to debug the issue is to raise the logging level with the following change to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[logging]
level=DEBUG
```

Then run the following to get better messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

I see the same issue on 4-5 Ubuntu machines that I manage, but desktop machines with wired connections. On most of these machines, the NetworkManager state cycles with messages like these:

```
Dec  7 01:36:56 vandebun-home whoopsie[1483]: [01:36:56] offline
Dec  7 01:36:56 vandebun-home dbus-daemon[890]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=891 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec  7 01:36:56 vandebun-home systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec  7 01:36:56 vandebun-home dbus-daemon[890]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec  7 01:36:56 vandebun-home systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec  7 01:36:57 vandebun-home NetworkManager[891]: <info>  [1638862617.8397] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec  7 01:36:57 vandebun-home whoopsie[1483]: [01:36:57] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  7 01:36:57 vandebun-home whoopsie[1483]: [01:36:57] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  7 01:36:57 vandebun-home whoopsie[1483]: [01:36:57] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Dec  7 01:36:59 vandebun-home whoopsie[1483]: [01:36:59] online
Dec  7 01:37:08 vandebun-home systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec  7 01:45:01 vandebun-home CRON[1667743]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Dec  7 01:47:17 vandebun-home NetworkManager[891]: <info>  [1638863237.3144] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec  7 01:47:17 vandebun-home whoopsie[1483]: [01:47:17] offline
```

Notice in the logs above, the difference between the `offline` and `online` message from `whoopsie` is only a few seconds. To summarize what's happening in these logs, the NetworkManager runs a check every 5 minutes (300 seconds, see `CONNECTIVITY` in `man NetworkManager.conf`) where the [connectivity check](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/snap-configuration/connectivity-check) fails and it goes offline. Then it immediately runs another connectivity check that passes and it comes back online. The time to come back online is only a few seconds in these particular logs, but on other machines it's minutes, and this is a problem.

With debug logging, I see this during the connectivity check that brings the NetworkManager offline:

```
Dec  7 14:39:49 vandebun-home gnome-control-c[1709862]: Failed fetch permissions from flatpak permission store: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for location
Dec  7 14:40:17 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909617.4571] ndisc-lndp[0x5634385a0e20,"enp3s0"]: processing libndp events
Dec  7 14:40:20 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909620.1503] connectivity: (tun0,IPv6,142) start request to 'http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/' (try resolving 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com' using systemd-resolved)
Dec  7 14:40:20 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909620.1521] connectivity: (tun0,IPv6,142) can't resolve a name via systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoNameServers: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
Dec  7 14:40:20 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909620.3694] connectivity: (tun0,IPv6,142) check completed: LIMITED; check failed: (6) Couldn't resolve host name
Dec  7 14:40:26 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909626.1534] connectivity: (tun0,IPv4,143) skip connectivity check due to no global route configured
Dec  7 14:40:26 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909626.1535] connectivity: (tun0,IPv4,143) check completed: LIMITED; no global route configured
Dec  7 14:41:09 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909669.5394] connectivity: (docker0,IPv6,144) start request to 'http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/' (try resolving 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com' using systemd-resolved)
Dec  7 14:41:09 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909669.5396] connectivity: (enp3s0,IPv6,145) start request to 'http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/' (try resolving 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com' using systemd-resolved)
Dec  7 14:41:09 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909669.5410] connectivity: (docker0,IPv6,144) can't resolve a name via systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoNameServers: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found
Dec  7 14:41:09 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909669.5509] connectivity: (enp3s0,IPv6,145) can't resolve a name via systemd-resolved: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchRR: 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com' does not have any RR of the requested type
Dec  7 14:41:09 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909669.9151] connectivity: (docker0,IPv6,144) check completed: LIMITED; check failed: (6) Couldn't resolve host name
Dec  7 14:41:09 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909669.9691] connectivity: (enp3s0,IPv6,145) check completed: LIMITED; check failed: (6) Couldn't resolve host name
Dec  7 14:41:15 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909675.5200] connectivity: (docker0,IPv4,146) skip connectivity check due to no global route configured
Dec  7 14:41:15 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909675.5201] connectivity: (docker0,IPv4,146) check completed: LIMITED; no global route configured
Dec  7 14:43:26 vandebun-home NetworkManager[1705563]: <debug> [1638909806.3332] connectivity: (enp3s0,IPv4,147) start request to 'http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/' (try resolving 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com' using systemd-resolved)
```

Notice that most of the errors are associated with `IPv6` in these logs. Presumably I'd be able to disable IPv6 on all my network interfaces and fix the problem, same as you.

### Alternative Solution

Another option is to disable connectivity checking:

```
[connectivity]
interval=0
```

For anyone who isn't roaming around on a laptop where you may experience a captive portal, there really aren't a lot of advantages to having this feature enabled (and for some, it may be a privacy concern anyways). This lets you get IPv6 working separately, later.

My theory (not sure about it, of course) is that the "regular" connectivity check (the one that runs every 5 minutes, when the machine is online already) isn't ready for IPv6. That is, it doesn't seem to have a sanity check that an IPv4 connection is enough. The connectivity check that runs after the NetworkManager is offline then only checks IPv4 (hence the cycle).